# How to disable back key button in Android

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova

I really want a straight forward answer as I always on the dead end. How to disable back button ( the hardware back button ) and where did I need to write the code to disable it ? I just want user of my apps to use the navigation on my apps.

Comment: I hope you have a good reason to disable it.  Users hate it when things don't work like they expect, like not having a back button.

Comment: You can override the `onBackPressed()` method on your activities to suppress the back button behavior, but you really shouldn't do this. If you can't architect your app in a way that allows using the back button, I suggest you re-think your app's navigation.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=How+to+disable+back+key+button+in+Android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs..............       plz use google

Comment: @climbage i'am making an online radio apps. so there will be no need for user to use the back button. the user can navigate it using the apps.

Answer (score 3):

after your onCreate just:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
```

Now if you want to do anyUpdate before backButton:

```
      @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
      //your function that updates
    }
```

Api :

Go to your manifest and see the  tab, the minimumSDK there should be 5.

```
SDK_INT value        Build.VERSION_CODES        Human Version Name       
1                    BASE                    Android 1.0
2                  BASE_1_1                  Android 1.1
3                   CUPCAKE                  Android 1.5 Cupcake
4                    DONUT                   Android 1.6 Donut
5                   ECLAIR                   Android 2.0 Eclair
6                   ECLAIR_0_1               Android 2.0.1 Eclair                  
7                   ECLAIR_MR1               Android 2.1 Eclair
8                   FROYO                    Android 2.2 Froyo
9                  GINGERBREAD               Android 2.3 Gingerbread
10                  GINGERBREAD_MR1           Android 2.3.3 Gingerbread
11                  HONEYCOMB                 Android 3.0 Honeycomb
12                  HONEYCOMB_MR1             Android 3.1 Honeycomb
13                  HONEYCOMB_MR2             Android 3.2 Honeycomb
14                  ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH        Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich
15                  ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1    Android 4.0.3 Ice Cream Sandwich
16                  JELLY_BEAN                Android 4.1 Jellybean
17                  JELLY_BEAN_MR1            Android 4.2 Jellybean
10000                CUR_DEVELOPMENT           Current Development Build
```

Comment: can i know where to paste this code.

Comment: Right after your oncreate finishes

Comment: already paste this code after oncreate. but still i can use my back button.

Comment: make sure, there is no code inside it. and also this supports only api level 5 and above.

Comment: sorry to ask, how to check my apps api level ?

Comment: still the code did not work after changing the minimum api level

Comment: Post the code that you have tried.

Comment: can i have your personal email as i have a lot of question to ask about phonegap on android.

Comment: Its there in my profile. And I havent worked with phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

Override the onKeyDown method within the activiy where you want to disable back key.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Note that returning true from onKeyDown will disable the default behavior

Comment: I'm sorry but your coding didn't work for me.

Comment: and how did you implemented my codes?

Comment: I paste this code on my java files. Can you assist me on where is the right place to paste it ?

Answer (score 0):

What [amalBit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2219600/amalbit) said is correct.If you have problem in overriding function, In Eclipse press Alt+Shift+S or Source Menu and select **Override/Implement Methods** and select `onBackPressed()` method and leave it back.

Comment: I already use override method but still my i can use my back button. This is so frustrating